# Print entire panel without scroll bar

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, panel, print-preview

I want to print whole area even though the panel has scroll bar.
Preview shows like below

[image]

but I want to print whole area like 
I tried client.height but get only screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Increase the height && Width of the form and remove the scroll bars..

Comment: Instead of printing the `Form/Panel` you can create an `RDLC` report and pass your data to the report and print report.

Comment: If this is a panel then you have a Paint event handler that draws this.  Move that code into another method that has at least a Graphics argument.  Now you can call it both from the Paint event handler and your PrintPage event handler.